# After Lollipop - when I add account there isn't an option to sync contacts/calenders - only email

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sync, email, calendar, sony-xperia

Just installed Lollipop on my Xperia Z3, now when I add an email account there is no option to sync contacts, calenders or tasks - only email. I used to be able to see my work calender (Outlook active xchange) but now the option to see/sync the calender is just not there. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the account, but the only option is to sync the email. All my work contacts have gone too.

Google account calender is still there. When I go to each account, Google is the only one with the option to sync the calender.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  I had to delete the account and do the manual setup instead of the automatic installation using m.outlook.com as the server name.  Once this was done it gave me the options to sync contacts, calendars, etc.  Before that on the automatic setup it was only giving me the option to sync email.

Hope this helps if you didn't get it working by now.  Odd thing was that mine just recently started doing this it wasn't right after the Lollipop upgrade.  So no idea why it started.